# Border not appearing at the top of every class

Tags: html, css

I'm using the jquery package 'listnav' to generate an alphabetical list. The HTML that gets rendered separates each letter into a specific class as such:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="ln-a">
    <a href="#">A text</a>
  </li>
  ... more 'A' items ...
  <li class="ln-b">
    <a href="#">B text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to apply a border at the top of every letter 'section' by using the first-child selector:

```
.ln-a:first-child{
    border-top:1px white solid; 
}
.ln-b:first-child {
    border-top:1px white solid; 
    }
```

I get the border above the 'A' section, but not above any of the subsequent sections. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.ln-b:first-child` matches the elements with class `ln-b` that are the first child of its parent.

In your case, the first child only has the class `ln-a`, so there is no match.

What you want is some kind of `:first-of-class`, but that doesn't exist.

However, you can set the styles to all `.ln-b` elements, and then remove them for those which are not the first one:

```
.ln-b { /* Set styles */ }
.ln-b + .ln-b { /* Remove styles */ }
```

```css
.ln-a,
.ln-b {
  border-top: 1px black solid;
}
.ln-a + .ln-a,
.ln-b + .ln-b {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="ln-a"><a href="#">A text</a></li>
  <li class="ln-a"><a href="#">A text</a></li>
  <li class="ln-b"><a href="#">B text</a></li>
  <li class="ln-b"><a href="#">B text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to 'close' the list.

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="ln-a">
    <a href="#">A text</a>
  </li>
  ... more 'A' items ...
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="ln-b">
    <a href="#">B text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The jquery package is building the html. I guess I could go in and change the js to close each ul after each section, but I'd rather not.. Anyway to do it without modifying the js?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ln-a:eq(0)').css('border-top','1px red solid');
     $('.ln-b:eq(0)').css('border-top','1px red solid');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="ln-a">
    <a href="#">A text</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ln-a">
    <a href="#">A1 text</a>
  </li>
    <li class="ln-a">
    <a href="#">A2 text</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ln-b">
    <a href="#">B text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```